# Why can't I connect a std_logic_vector signal to a port of type signed or unsigned

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

The numeric_std.vhdl says this:

```
  type UNSIGNED is array (NATURAL range <>) of STD_LOGIC;
  type SIGNED is array (NATURAL range <>) of STD_LOGIC;
```

Does this means that the unsigned and signed have std_logic as their subtypes?

Why then is it that when I have an entity with a port of signed or unsigned type and I connect a std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) to it, I get an error?

e.g

```
component dummy is
port(
    a: in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    b: in signed(3 downto 0);
    c: in unsigned(3 downto 0);
    d: out std_logic
);
end component;
```

If I port map a std_logic_vector to *b* or *c* I get errors:

```
Signal "b" is type ieee.std_logic_1164.STD_LOGIC_VECTOR; expecting type ieee.NUMERIC_STD.SIGNED.
```

Why?

Comment: Simply put they are different types. An actual in an association list may be a type conversion.  IEEE Std 1076-2008 6.5.7 Association lists, 6.5.7.1, para 11. Also see 9.3.6 Type conversions, where we find a SIGNED and a STD_LOGIC_VECTOR can be closely when they have the same element type and dimensionality (number of indices, 5.3.2 Array types).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although in your example `unsigned` and `signed` are both arrays of the same element type `std_logic`, this is not the same as a subtype. A subtype is when one type is a limited subset of another type, for example:

```
subtype my_type is std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
subtype eight_bit_int is integer range 0 to 255;
```

A feature of a subtype is that it can be automatically converted to and from the parent type, so I can do:

```
signal a : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
signal b : my_type;
signal c : integer;
signal d : eight_bit_int_type;
```

...

```
-- These should both work fine
b <= a;
c <= d;
```

If you want to connect differing types in a port map, you might have to use type casts or type conversions, or both. Using your example entity, you might write something like this:

```
signal a_actual : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
signal b_actual : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
signal c_actual : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
signal d_actual : std_logic;
```

...

```
-- Converting from std_logic_vector to signed or unsigned only requires a cast 
dummy_inst : dummy
port map(
    a => a_actual,
    b => std_logic_vector(b_actual),
    c => std_logic_vector(c_actual),
    d => actual
);
```

If you wanted to connect an input, for example `b` to an integer, you would have to use a type conversion and a cast, and the line would look like this:

```
b => std_logic_vector(to_signed(b_integer, 4)), -- 4 is the length of the port
```